# Open an .ics file via JavaScript / Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, icalendar

I have a downloaded ICS file via Angular2 on a desktop machine. I am trying to automatically open this file, at the moment the behavior i am seeing is that the file just downloads - it can be then opened. However, I would like to automatically invoke the default Mail client.

Code:

```
openICS(data: Response) {
    let payload = data.text();
    let blob = new Blob([payload], { type: 'text/calendar' });
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url, '_blank');
   }
```

Can anyone help?

Cheers

KH

Comment: I think this is an example of an XY problem (xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I have a service endpoint that outputs a string in iCalendar (.ics)  format. I need to open that data in the local Mail client. Writing it to a text file seemed like the best bet...

Comment: I think that showing the date on the page would a better option most of the time. Opening an additional application might be annoying. Additionally, I'm not sure ics is a common format, not every user might be able to open it.

Comment: Yes but this is for a calendar export feature so you can add it to your local calendar. ICalendar is an open standard thats supported by most (maybe all) the major calendar / mail clients.